# How to eliminate extra padding on resize

Tags: jquery, resize

I am trying to do something which seems like it should be simple but it isn't.  The actual application is more complicated than the sample here but this reproduces what I am struggling with.  I do most of my development with IE9 but I've tried this out with other browsers and seen the same issue.

I have a DIV I want resized according to the browser window size.  Mostly the code works except if the user shrinks the browser window you end up with extra padding which was clearly allocated for a scrollbar which isn't needed (some of the time).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Resize Test</title>
    <script src="/SharedLib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resize(e) {
            $("#sized-content").width($(window).width() - 10); // 2 x 5px border = 10
            $("#sized-content").height($(window).height() - 10);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(resize);
            resize();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <div id="sized-content" style="border: 5px solid red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I have found 2 fixes both of which are highly undesirable:

1. Call resize again off a timer. Very noticeably blinky.
2. Set body style to "overflow: hidden".

What I have determined from debugging is that $(document).width() is greater than $(window).width() and thus the scrollbar is allocated.  But the resize function changes the content size to correct this and yet the scrollbar does not go away until sometime later when the required document width is updated AND another resize takes place.

It sure seems to me this extra scrollbar padding should be able to be eliminated without a hack.

Comment: Do you really have to solve this problem with Javascript? Looks like you could solve this easily with CSS. Use position absolute or fixed.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem as the sizing issue is the same no matter how you position things. In our application there is a lot of calculations going on which can't be done with CSS as there are lots of borders and margins which need to be factored in thus requiring javascript.